# reinstallation of ubuntu 14.04 failure

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on a 500 GB external hard disk. It has 20 GB / partition ,5 GB partition for linux swap and 475 GB /home partition.
Because of problems I tried reinstallation of ubuntu 14.04 from live usb on the
20 GB partition, opting for formatting only that partition. Everything went fine till nearly the end, "update grub" operation which failed.I was given an option to continue without boot-loader which I declined. I tried to cancel the
reinstallation which was declared a failure.
Now fdisk shows my hard disk to be 500 GB but says it does not contain a valid
partition table. Gparted shows only 475 GB "unallocated" space.
I want to get back my data on /home partition and also to reinstall ubuntu 14.04 again.
How do I go about it?
After few hours: OK. I have got my partitions back using testdisk.All my data
is in tact. However I still need to reinstall ubuntu 14.04. How shall I proceed and any ideas of what to do so that there is not another failure of
reinstallation?